# Word365 Align equations to equal sign

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment, equations, microsoft-word-365

Trying to align the equation (see photos below) to the equal signs. Not having any luck and it seems all the advice on the web relates to older version of word. Tried align equations but they're still misaligned.

Original alignment of equations:

[image]

Clicking equation alignment option:

[image: clicking equation alignment option]

Result of equation alignment:

[image: result of equation alignment]

Answer (score 2):

To enter the line breaks (new lines) for the equation on Windows, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. On Mac, it should be <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>. Do this allow the equation although spread on multiple lines to be considered as one.

Then, select the equation, then click `Align at`.

[image: IMG:]

This will be your result:

[image: IMG:]

Looks like you are using a Mac. I am not sure if the menu are 100% the same. The screenshots are from a Windows PC.